# Insert columnA values of Table 1 into another table if match occur

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables.Table A has 4 columns. And table B has two columns.I want to insert value of one column of tabel A from one column of table B based on condtion if id matches.
how i can do this ? For example  if [Movieid] in 1st table =[IMDBid] in second table then insert [count] of table 1=[CB] in table 2.
i want to do it once for full table.
[column] -> these are colums
i m using sql server.

Tabel 1 : Movieid,count,
Tabel 2: IMDBid, CB
Results which i want: i want to insert values of CB column in count where Movieid=IMDBid

Tabel 1 :
(Nick Id,MovieId,Rating,MovId)-> (1,4972,6.25,?)(1,24216,7.25,?)
Tabel 2 :
(Imdbid,Title,ImdbPyId,Id)-> (4972,hello,32450,1)(24216,hi,62450,2)

Insert /fill value of MovId(tabel1) using values Id(tabel2)where MovieId(tabel1)==Imdbid(tabel2)

Comment: Please edit your question with sample data and desired results.  Also, decide which database you are using:  MySQL or SQL Server?

Comment: i m using sql server

Comment: tabel schema  what is that. i m new ? plz explain

Comment: Provide a good example with table schema

Comment: You added it, no problem. Can you add some sample data for both tables.

Comment: i m trying to add image of tables but cant post due to less repuatation

Comment: Add the data using the space between data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solution is   UPDATE tabl1
   SET count = (SELECT CB FROM tabl2 WHERE IMDBid = Movieid)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like,

```
   UPDATE tabl1
   SET count = (SELECT CB FROM tabl2 WHERE IMDBid = Movieid)
```

But it is  gonna blow up if you have multiple values returning from the `subquery`.

So make sure to use the appropriate function to get the single value from that subquery whichever meets your requirements.

If your tables have `1:1` relationship then it should be fine. But if it is `1:n` then you need to use either aggragate functions or the `TOP 1` clause in that subqyery.